# How to fix conflict Zoomooz.js with JQueryUI autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, autocomplete, conflict, zoomooz

When I put zoomooz.js in a web page with jqueryui autocomplete, it work only the first time, drop-down menu no longer accept mouse click. To work I move the mouse on the target and click Enter Key on keyboard.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zoomooz/1.1.6/jquery.zoomooz.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
  $( function() {
var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  "BASIC",
  "C",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
  } );
</script>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>

<img class="zoomTarget" data-targetsize="0.05" data-closeclick="true" src="file.png">
```

## tags autocomplete not work always, only the first time, but if I delete zoomooz, it work fine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you see any errors in Console when the page loads? Do you see any after you try to load Autocomplete? Based onm what I see in GitHub, it does not appear to have conflicting NameSpace, so it's hard to see if there would be an issue.

Comment: Also it looks like youare not using jQuery UI Autocomplete: https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ `minChars`, `autoFill`, and `mustMatch` are not part of that library.

Comment: excuse me, I copied zoomerang but it's zoomooz.js. Now you can run code and see the problem

Comment: Looks like the `click` event is conflicting on the 2nd round. The menu comes up but you cannot select an item in the menu.

Comment: clickTarget.on("click", function(evt) {

            // closeclick not available here...
            if(settings.closeclick && zoomTarget.hasClass("selectedZoomTarget")) {
                settings.root.click();
            } else {
                zoomTarget.zoomTo(settings);
            }
            evt.stopPropagation();
        });

the problem is in evt.stopPropagation(); I think

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to replicate the issue as you described it. If you're using jQuery UI Autocomplete, you must use the correct options. Here is a working example.

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];

  $("#numean").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    minLength: 1,
    open: function() {
      console.log("Open Triggered");
    },
    focus: function() {
      console.log("Focus Triggered");
      return true;
    },
    select: function() {
      console.log("Select Triggered");
      return true;
    }
  });

  $(".zoomTarget").zoomTo({
    duration: 1000,
    closeclick: true,
    targetsize: 0.05
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/zoomooz/1.1.6/jquery.zoomooz.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="numean" value="">
<br />
<img class="zoomTarget" width="50%" src="https://i.imgur.com/FThOLcL.jpg">
```

See More:

- [jQuery UI | AutoComplete](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)
- [Zoomooz.js](https://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/)

**Update**

After some testing, I can see that bubbling of the `click` event is being disrupted. For example, in the example above, on the first round, everything works as expected. On the second search, you can <kbd>↓</kbd> to your selection and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and `focus` and `select` is triggered. Yet if you try to move the mouse and click the item, only `focus` is triggered. I am pretty sure the conflict comes from the `closeclick: true` setting. I think this is listening on a higher scope after a Zoom then the click event for `select`.

I would advise setting `closeclick: false` and then creating another closing method. Either a button or some other more specific event.

You may also notice I loaded Zoomooz first before jQuery. I noticed if they loaded in the other order, there was some weird `window` conflicts.

Comment: excuse me, I copied zoomerang but it's zoomooz.js. Now you can run code and see the problem

Comment: I can't find the solution, I'm going crazy. I think I will have to give up the zoom